# docx to PDF conversion using docx4j

Tags: docx4j

I am trying to convert docx file to pdf using docx4j. But I am getting an error [image: error message]
[image: error message]

What I found that docx4j older versions were not able to support shapes inserted in the docs for pdf conversion.
Does any current version of docx4J, documents4j and docx4j-export-fo combination has these supported?

In the input file there were few lines drawn or inserted, as a place holder to populate values, these lines are erroring out while converting to PDF

````
```

    import org.docx4j.Docx4J;
    import org.docx4j.Docx4jProperties;
    import org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage;
    
    import org.slf4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
    
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    
    
    
    public class Main {
        
       private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);
       public static final int FLAG_EXPORT_PREFER_XSL = 0;
    
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           
           Docx4jProperties.setProperty(
                    "com.plutext.converter.URL", 
                    "https://converter-eval.plutext.com:443/v1/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/convert");
            
            try {
                InputStream templateInputStream = new FileInputStream("C:\\Documents\\Output_docx\\Directors.docx");
                WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(templateInputStream);            
    
    
    
               String outputfilepath = "C:\\Documents\\Output_docx\\Example_output_2.pdf";
                FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputfilepath);
                Docx4J.toPDF(wordMLPackage,os);
                os.flush();
                os.close();
            } catch (Throwable e) {
    
                LOGGER.warn("Conversion Error!");
    
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    
    
    
    }

```
````

Comment: Thanks for confirming, docx4j till date can't draw shapes or pictorial objects like lines

Answer (score 0):

See https://www.docx4java.org/blog/2020/09/office-pptxxlsxdocx-to-pdf-to-in-docx4j-8-2-3/ which compares the 3 approaches for generating PDF output.

In summary to handle those objects, use the documents4j approach (which uses Word), or Microsoft Graph.